# What is the correct syntax for __eq__(other) in Python

Tags: python

My instructions were to return True if the student_id's were equal to each other and False if the names were equal to each other. I believe that I am using the 'other' part incorrectly and I've looked it up and have not been able to solve it

This is my code

```
def __eq__(self, other):
   if self.student_id == self.student_id:
       return True
   elif self.name == self.name:
       return False
```

This is the error it's returning

```
AssertionError: <src.student.Student object at 0x039C1490> == <src.student.Student object at 0x039C1650> : Student [Captain Chris, 00001960, Computer Engineering, 0.00 F] and [Captain Chris, 00001961, Computer Engineering, 0.00 F] are not equal.
```

Comment: You should probably be checking that both the name and ID are equal are returning true if they are. It doesn't seem to make sense to return False if the names are the same.

Comment: Also you could fall through both of those cases and implicitly return `None`

Comment: You are not using `other` in that method, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: By that definition, wouldn't no student be equal to itself?  That's a pretty strange defintion of equality.

Comment: I don't think I worded my question right. If two student id's are equal then they are the same student so it should return True. If they have the same name they are not necessarily the same student so it should return false unless they have the same id as well

Comment: So, comparing the name is pretty irrelevant, isn't it? If they have the same id, they're the same student. In any other case, they aren't.

Comment: In your own words, when the method is called, what will `self` and `other` refer to? You say you want to check whether "the student_id's were equal to each other"; there are two such ids; how should you expect to refer to them, given the first answer?

Answer (score 0):

You are testing if `self.student_id` is equal to iself. What you should test is if the `student_id` variable of your current object (ie `self`) is equal to the other `student_id`

```
self.student_id == other.student_id
```

Though, are your sure to understand what you are doing here? You are basically testing this:

- If the student_id is equal to the other's student_id: equal is True
- BUT if they are not equal, and if their names are the same: equal is false (???).
- Last: if their student_id AND their names are different, **eq** do not return anything, which is a problem.

Maybe you meant to do:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
   if self.student_id == other.student_id:
       return True
   elif self.name == other.name:
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

Which could be happily simplified to:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
   return self.student_id == other.student_id or self.name == other.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, student_id):
        self.name = name
        self.student_id = student_id

    def __eq__(self, other):
        status = False
        if self.student_id == other.student_id:
            status = True
        return status

s1 = student("Davidd", 10)
s2 = student("David", 11)
print(s1 == s2)
```

> False

```
s1 = student("David", 10)
s2 = student("David", 11)
print(s1 == s2)
```

> False

```
s1 = student("David", 11)
s2 = student("David", 11)
print(s1 == s2)
```

> True

```
s1 = student("David", 101)
s2 = student("Davids", 101)
print(s1 == s2)
```

> True